# Simplifying/Combining if statement logic (When using Numbers)

Tags: javascript, calculated-field

I have been looking around, googling here and there, how to properly code a very simplistic calculator. More specifically a Boolean calculator with set values. If I've lost you, bear with me I'll try to explain.

I have the need to use checkboxes to set a `input.value`. This value will be picked up elsewhere in a Web-Java applet; hence the need for `input.value`.

To save time and confusion I have built a small snippet using [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/51/), and realised I have no real idea how to work with Numbers in JS. Everything I have learned so far has been self taught using the web and various other sources.

I struggle in understanding efficient ways of writing logic, but can scrape by, by writing really simplistic logic. The more I write and ask questons the more I learn. So I've come here seeking some advice on how to minimize my given code snippet.

---

> It's not robust, It's not elegant; but it's my route in.

```js
function calculate() {
  // set the variables
  var a = document.getElementById('checkboxopt');
  var b = document.getElementById('checkboxopt1');
  var c = document.getElementById('pnvar');
  var d = document.getElementById('adjvar');
  var e = document.getElementById('adjvar2');
  var i = 0;
  var i2 = 0;

  if (a.checked) {
    console.log('Arg True')
    i = i + 80;
    d.value = i;
  } else {
    console.log('Arg False')
    d.value = i;
  }

  if (b.checked) {
    console.log('Arg True')
    i2 = i2 + 30;
    e.value = i2
  } else {
    console.log('Arg False')
    e.value = i2;
  }
  console.log(i, i2);
  c.value = i + i2;
};

var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
[].forEach.call(cbs, function(cb) {
  cb.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    calculate();
  });
});

calculate();
```

```css
.editoropt {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 160px;
  background: #f8f8ff;
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
#checkboxopt {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
#checkboxopt1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.pnvar {
  width: 95%;
}
input:-moz-read-only {
  /* For Firefox */
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
}
input:read-only {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Default 80mm </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" checked />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Add 30mm </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt1" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt2" id="opt2" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
<div class="editoropt">
  <input class="pnvar" id="pnvar" name="pnvar" placeholder="Null" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { event.preventDefault(); return false; }" value="" class="required" type="text">
  <input name="adjvar" class="pnvar" id="adjvar" readonly value="0">
  <input name="adjvar" class="pnvar" id="adjvar2" readonly value="0">
</div>
</div>
```

---

> **My Question**
>
> What would be the best way to simplify my given code, and improve it's performance. More Specifically, is there a more simplistic way of working with numbers within JS? Or am I on the right track with my current snippet?
>
> If you are an experienced JS developer how would you tackle the desired result above?

A little detailed guidance is what I'm hoping for.

Comment: If you code is working fine and objective of this question is improvements/optimisations, please post it on [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Rajesh I had done, I was instructed to post it here. :(

Comment: Alright. But you are looking for improvements. Right?

Comment: In theory yes. I don't think my code is written correctly.

Comment: I have tried to improve your code and have posted an answer. Feel free to ask any queries

Answer (score 1):

First, try to make code as reusable as possible. So,

```js
if (a.checked) {
  console.log('Arg True')
  i = i + 80;
  d.value = i;
} else {
  console.log('Arg False')
  d.value = i;
}

if (b.checked) {
  console.log('Arg True')
  i2 = i2 + 30;
  e.value = i2
} else {
  console.log('Arg False')
  e.value = i2;
}
```

can be replaced as

```js
function dummy(el, val) {
  i2 += el.checked ? val : 0;
}
```

Second, do not have inline functions in HTML. It will dirty your HTML and make debug difficult. You should wrap all listeners in a wrapper function. This will enable you to even export all of them to separate file and you will know where to look.

Third, instead of hard coding value `80` or `30` in your code, make a map or bind it to element using `data-attribute`

Fourth and more Important one, use better variable names. `a-e` or `i, i1, i2` are bad names. Only you will understand your code (till you are in context). Always use precise meaningful name. This will help in long run. I have even kept function names as long as 30+ chars just to define its purpose.

Also try to break your code in smaller functions. This will increase scope for reusing them.

You can refer [updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/54/) and ask any queries, if you have.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your post. You've compacted the code by quite a large amount. I clearly still have a lot to learn. Could you eplain the purpose of this line `total += (+val * (el.checked ? 1 : -1));` and how it functions?

Comment: @Beaniie You have to *add/subtract* value as you select/un-select. So `(el.checked ? 1 : -1)` will return `1`  if value is checked and `-1` if not. If value is un-selected, you are subtracting its value from total and from necessary variable